# Syntax error with some JS/jquery code regarding });

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting an error on some JS code for a content window I'm trying to create. I'm getting told that }); shouldn't be where it is, but I can't understand what the problem is. Am I using terms from an outdated jquery?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.contentwindow_trigger').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        if ($('#contentwindow').length > 0) { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

            $('#contentwindow').show();
        }
        else { 
            var contentwindow =

            '<div id="contentwindow">' +

                '<p>Click to close</p>' +

                '<section id="content">' +
                    '<img src="#" />' +
                '</section>' +

            '</div>';
            $('body').append(contentwindow);
        }
    }); //HERE

    $('#contentwindow').on('click', function() {
        $('#contentwindow').hide();
    });
});
```

The fault is where it says HERE, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code has not syntax error. What is the error?

Comment: I get no syntax error here with your code.  Is this **all** of your code?

Comment: Looks fine to me. the whitespace in your declaration of `var contentwindow` may be confusing the interpreter.

Comment: @jbabey, You can have all the whitespace there that you want.  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2

Comment: @jbabey I don't think it's causing the problem.

Comment: @Brad except if the whitespace causes the compiler to infer a semicolon where it doesn't belong: `return \n a+b`

Comment: What is telling you that the `});` should not be there? Your IDE?

Comment: This code compiles fine in the form the OP posted it..Has ANYONE else got a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

remove the $  from this line your code

```
function($) {
```

to

```
function() {
```

/

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.contentwindow_trigger').click(function(e) {
            // Click event code
        });

        $('#contentwindow').on('click', function() {
            $('#contentwindow').hide();
        });
    });
```

One more change required which does not affect the Syntax error in the page is that I see that you are dynamically adding an element and associating a click event to it .

You need to **delegate the** event for such case and the Event might not work

```
$('body').on('click','#contentwindow' , function() {
        $('#contentwindow').hide();
    });
```

Comment: @Brad .. Seems like that is not the problem.. my bad ;)

Comment: @Sushanth--: The `$` parameter is even needed to ensure that `$ == jQuery` inside the [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this sript:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contentwindow_trigger').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        if ($('#contentwindow').length > 0) { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

            $('#contentwindow').show();
        }
        else { 
            var contentwindow =

            '<div id="contentwindow">' +

                '<p>Click to close</p>' +

                '<section id="content">' +
                    '<img src="#" />' +
                '</section>' +

            '</div>';
            $('body').append(contentwindow);
        }
    }); //HERE

    $('#contentwindow').on('click', function() {
        $('#contentwindow').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Playing "spot the difference"?

Comment: So tell us, what did you change?

Comment: So you _do_ want me to play "spot the difference". I see _one_ change with _no_ effect on any syntax error being present.

Comment: Alright guys, i will back off..long day of coding..head hurts.. will delete my comment since it caused Enve some anger..Apologies friend :)

Comment: Its not all my code, obviously it links from an HTML doc and a CSS as well as jquery and a css for my webfont.

Comment: Its just not working though, I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: @JoeTaylor, Can't help you, since you haven't posted the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Could it possibly be a problem in my HTML? As that's my whole JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the syntax error you're seeing is, but it seems to work fine in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xV58c/

One change I made there that may help you.  Instead of:

```
$('#contentwindow').on('click', function() {
    $('#contentwindow').hide();
});
```

I did:

```
$('body').on('click', '#contentwindow', function() {
    $('#contentwindow').hide();
});
```

which uses the "on" method in a way that allows the containing element ("body" in this case) to deal with events on elements below, even elements generated that way that #contentwindow is.

Hope this helps.